# Unable to connect to serial device; no /dev/ttySx

Tags: rhel, serial-port

I wrote a Java application that connects to the serial port of the GSM modem. On Windows the serial ports have names like COM3, but in Linux Redhat 6.0 I had to switch to something like ttySx (X is number that came after S in `/dev/` directory). When I plug my modem in to Linux there are no serial entries in `/dev` (just ttyUSBx), but on Windows it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, those (`ttyUSB{0..2}`) **are** the serial devices and are the ones you want your application to use.

Comment: I used these (ttyUSB{0..2}) but it does not work either

Comment: Please update your question with information on how exactly it does not work (what, you're trying to do, what you're expecting and what you're seeing)